# debian testing : i3 not starting

Tags: linux, debian, xorg, i3, wayland

I am using debian testing and after an update, i3 will not start anymore. When I start a session with it, all I see is a black screen and I have to reboot the computer. I can only use gnome. It did not happend recently but maybe two months ago.
Also, in gnome, if I open a terminal and start typing in it, then the keyboard will not work in chrome.
I have no idea where to look to debug this.. I tried to review system I can't find anything unusual.

Comment: Is the screen totally black or is there a mouse cursor? Can you switch to another virtual console instead of rebooting?

Comment: @icarus The screen is totally black, but I tried to switch to another virtual console and it worked. I typed in "startx" and it went black again, then I went to the first black screen and it took me back to my login screen. I logged-in, and this time it worked; now, I see that I have wayland and xorg running at the same time, so maybe a debian update made wayland as the default, and now i3 is not working. I am not sure how to set xorg back as a default x-server, but I will try to find out.

Comment: I uncommented the line `#WaylandEnable=false` in the file `/etc/gdm3/daemon.conf`, now wayland is not running but I still have the same result.